# true format for only digit in jsf inputTex

Tags: validation, jsf

i have inputTex in jsf that must only digit data on it.i have this code.is this pattern true?

```
@FacesValidator("namelValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator{

    private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "[0-9]";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public NAMElValidator(){
        pattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
                         Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if(!matcher.matches()){

            FacesMessage msg =
                    new FacesMessage("E-mail validation failed.",
                            "Invalid name format.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question has a slighly broken code formatting. Please use the "edit" link below your question and fix it.

Comment: I'm not certain this would be an email validator?

Comment: If the sole purpose/intention of this validator is to use a regular expression - RegEx then, this can be achieved just by using `<f:validateRegex pattern="RegEX">`. There is no need to dance with a custom validator, in this case.

Comment: yes,it isnt for e-mail.if I want to have validator for firstName that inputTex accept only character but no digit and i want use client side validator what is solution?

Answer (score -1):

That's just one digit. You could use

```
private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "[0-9]+";
```

or more compactly

```
private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "\d+";
```

Comment: in backBean i have this code,how can avoid in doadd() if above validation class is false?

Comment: If you have a validator associated with a field, it will prevent the values in the backing bean from being updated if validation fails, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.